# SQLException when using orderBy() in ORMLite

Tags: java, android, ormlite

I am a beginner in ORMLite for android.  I need to select certain rows from my `Accounts` table in alphabetical order of the "name" column values and also shows the row with name as "Others" should be at the last of the list.  I used `queryBuilder().orderByRaw(...)` for getting this but it results SQLException.Below is the complete stacktrace of that exception.

```
07-22 12:06:29.730: W/System.err(581): java.sql.SQLException: Problems executing Android query: SELECT * FROM `accounts` WHERE ((`parent_id` = 1 AND `active` = 1 ) AND `id` NOT IN (5 ,43 ) ) ORDER BY CASE WHEN name=Others THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,name 
07-22 12:06:29.750: W/System.err(581):  at com.j256.ormlite.misc.SqlExceptionUtil.create(SqlExceptionUtil.java:22)
07-22 12:06:29.750: W/System.err(581):  at com.j256.ormlite.android.AndroidCompiledStatement.getCursor(AndroidCompiledStatement.java:184)
07-22 12:06:29.760: W/System.err(581):  at com.j256.ormlite.android.AndroidCompiledStatement.runQuery(AndroidCompiledStatement.java:65)
07-22 12:06:29.771: W/System.err(581):  at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.SelectIterator.<init>(SelectIterator.java:55)
07-22 12:06:29.780: W/System.err(581):  at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.StatementExecutor.buildIterator(StatementExecutor.java:247)
07-22 12:06:29.790: W/System.err(581):  at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.StatementExecutor.query(StatementExecutor.java:196)
 07-22 12:06:29.800: W/System.err(581):     at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.query(BaseDaoImpl.java:265)
07-22 12:06:29.800: W/System.err(581):  at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.QueryBuilder.query(QueryBuilder.java:361)
07-22 12:06:29.820: W/System.err(581):  at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.Where.query(Where.java:503)
07-22 12:06:29.820: W/System.err(581):  at com.fort.sample.db.SaveMoneyController.getListData(SaveMoneyController.java:183)
07-22 12:06:29.830: W/System.err(581):  at com.fort.sample.view.MainActivity.loadExpense(MainActivity.java:338)
07-22 12:06:29.840: W/System.err(581):  at com.fort.sample.view.MainActivity.listClicked(MainActivity.java:248)
07-22 12:06:29.860: W/System.err(581):  at com.fort.sample.view.MainActivity.access$10(MainActivity.java:233)
07-22 12:06:29.860: W/System.err(581):  at com.fort.sample.view.MainActivity$8.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:216)
07-22 12:06:29.860: W/System.err(581):  at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
07-22 12:06:29.899: W/System.err(581):  at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3513)
07-22 12:06:29.899: W/System.err(581):  at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1812)
07-22 12:06:29.921: W/System.err(581):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
07-22 12:06:29.930: W/System.err(581):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-22 12:06:29.940: W/System.err(581):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-22 12:06:29.940: W/System.err(581):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
07-22 12:06:29.940: W/System.err(581):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-22 12:06:29.940: W/System.err(581):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-22 12:06:29.940: W/System.err(581):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
07-22 12:06:29.940: W/System.err(581):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
07-22 12:06:29.940: W/System.err(581):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-22 12:06:29.979: W/System.err(581): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: Others: , while compiling: SELECT * FROM `accounts` WHERE ((`parent_id` = 1 AND `active` = 1 ) AND `id` NOT IN (5 ,43 ) ) ORDER BY CASE WHEN name=Others THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,name 
07-22 12:06:30.059: W/System.err(581):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
07-22 12:06:30.059: W/System.err(581):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.compile(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:92)
07-22 12:06:30.069: W/System.err(581):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:65)
07-22 12:06:30.080: W/System.err(581):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:83)
07-22 12:06:30.089: W/System.err(581):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:49)
07-22 12:06:30.099: W/System.err(581):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:42)
07-22 12:06:30.110: W/System.err(581):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1356)
07-22 12:06:30.119: W/System.err(581):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1324)
07-22 12:06:30.119: W/System.err(581):  at com.j256.ormlite.android.compat.BasicApiCompatibility.rawQuery(BasicApiCompatibility.java:15)
07-22 12:06:30.129: W/System.err(581):  at com.j256.ormlite.android.AndroidCompiledStatement.getCursor(AndroidCompiledStatement.java:180)
07-22 12:06:30.129: W/System.err(581):  ... 24 more
```

And Below is the code that I used

```
listCoaAct=new ArrayList<COAAccount>();
List<Integer> idList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
idList.add(5);
idList.add(43);
List<Accounts> getCoa = dbHelper.getAccountsDao().queryBuilder()
    .orderByRaw("CASE WHEN name=Others THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,name")
    .where().eq("parent_id",parentId).and().eq("active", true)
        .and().notIn("id", idList).query();
```

How can I solve my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`name=Others` in the CASE statement of Order by clause is the problem here.

Here, `Others` is a string literal so it should be enclosed in single-quote (') like:

```
CASE WHEN name='Others' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,name
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason is right there in your error message:

> no such column: Others

You have to set "Others" in quotes, otherwise your SQL engine will try and find a column with that name.